# POST, DELTE,GET operation RestController spring boot with composite key

Tags: java, spring, rest

I'm looking for the correct way to implements this operations (delete, post, get) in my controller class using **JPA**.

Here's my code i'm not sure about post if it is correct but really delete is causing problem because HttpDelete from Apache Component doesn't have setEntity method for request body.

The DAO :

```
@Repository
public interface PiecesReparationDAO extends JpaRepository<PiecesReparation, Integer>{
    PiecesReparation findById(PieceRId id);
    PiecesReparation findById_Id_produit(int id);
    PiecesReparation findById_Id_Reparation(int id);
    void deleteById(PieceRId id);
}
```

the model :

```
@Entity
public class PiecesReparation {

   @EmbeddedId
   PieceRId id;

   @MapsId("id_produit")
   @ManyToOne(optional = false)
   @JoinColumn(name = "id_produit", referencedColumnName = "id")
   private Produit product;

   @MapsId("id_reparation")
   @ManyToOne(optional = false)
   @JoinColumn(name = "", referencedColumnName = "id")
   private Reparation reparation;



   private Timestamp date_utilisation;

   public PieceRId getPieceRId(){
       return this.id;
   }
   public void setPieceRId(PieceRId id){
       this.id=id;
   }

    public Timestamp getDateUtilisation(){
        return this.date_utilisation;
    }

    public void setDateUtilisation(Timestamp date){
        this.date_utilisation=date;
    }



}
```

classe PieceRId :

```
    @Embeddable
   public class PieceRId implements Serializable {
   int id_produit;
   int id_reparation;

   //implements equals and hashCode
   public int getIdProduit(){
       return this.id_produit;
   }

   public int getIdReparation(){
       return this.id_reparation;
   }

   public PieceRId(){

   }

   public PieceRId(int id_produit, int id_reparation){
       this.id_produit=id_produit;
       this.id_reparation=id_reparation;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean equals(Object o){
       if(o ==null) return false;
       if(((PieceRId)o).getIdProduit() == this.getIdProduit() &&
               ((PieceRId)o).getIdReparation() == this.getIdReparation())
           return true;
       else return false;
   }

   @Override
   public int hashCode() { 
       return Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(id_produit)+String.valueOf(id_reparation));
   }
}
```

The controller :

```
@RestController
public class PiecesReparationController {
   @Autowired
    private PiecesReparationDAO piecesReparationDao;

    @GetMapping(value = "/Pieces")
    public ArrayList<PiecesReparation> listePiecesReparations() {
        ArrayList<PiecesReparation> listePiecesReparations= new ArrayList() ;
        Iterable<PiecesReparation> piecesReparations = piecesReparationDao.findAll();
         MappingJacksonValue produitsFiltres = new MappingJacksonValue(piecesReparations);
         for (Iterator<PiecesReparation> i = piecesReparations.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
            PiecesReparation item = i.next();
               listePiecesReparations.add(item);
         }
         return listePiecesReparations;
    }

    //Récupérer un produit par son Id
    @GetMapping(value = "/Pieces/{id}")
    public PiecesReparation selectionPiecesReparation(@PathVariable PieceRId id) {
        return piecesReparationDao.findById(id);
    }

    //ajouter un produit
    @PostMapping(value = "/Pieces")
    public ResponseEntity<?> ajouterPiecesReparation(@RequestBody PieceReparationDTO pieceReparation) {

        PiecesReparation pieceR = new PiecesReparation();
        pieceR.setPieceRId(new PieceRId(pieceReparation.getIdProduit(), pieceReparation.getIdReparation()));
        pieceR.setDateUtilisation(pieceReparation.getDateUtilisation());
        PiecesReparation piecesReparationAdded =  piecesReparationDao.save(pieceR);

        if (piecesReparationAdded == null)
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY);
        else return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.CREATED);

    }

   @DeleteMapping(value = "/Pieces/{id}")
   public void supprimerPiecesReparation(@PathVariable PieceRId id) {

       piecesReparationDao.delete(id);
   }

   @DeleteMapping(value = "/Pieces")
   public void supprimerPiecesReparation2(@RequestBody PieceRId id) {
       PiecesReparation pieceR= new PiecesReparation();
       pieceR.setPieceRId(new PieceRId(id.getIdProduit(),id.getIdReparation()));
       piecesReparationDao.delete(pieceR);
   }




  @PutMapping (value = "/Pieces")
  public void updateProduit(@RequestBody PieceReparationDTO pieceReparation) {
       PiecesReparation pieceR = new PiecesReparation();
        pieceR.setPieceRId(new PieceRId(pieceReparation.getIdProduit(), pieceReparation.getIdReparation()));
        pieceR.setDateUtilisation(pieceReparation.getDateUtilisation());
        PiecesReparation piecesReparationAdded =  piecesReparationDao.save(pieceR);
  } 
}
```

method to consume web service :

```
public static void deleteRest(int id, String type){

        try{
        CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();  

            HttpDelete deleteRequest = new HttpDelete(getUrl(type)+"/"+id);
            HttpResponse response=client.execute(deleteRequest);
            System.out.print("response code : 
 "+response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
            client.close();
        }catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } 



    }
```

I know how to delete with url and path variable but don't how to do with request body because no setEntity method. I'm not sure it it's ok for the others operations if it's implemented correctly. Thanks.

Comment: If your ID type is `PieceRId`, why are you defining your repository ID type as `Integer`?

Comment: forgot about it thanks. I did the changes and i had to change find by Id by this : **Optional<PiecesReparation> findById(PieceRId id);** Don't know what means optional because of a clashes with findBydId(ID)  CRUD Repository

Comment: ID is enough for deletion. Why u need body? If you need this use post method .

Comment: how we use a path variable with the object PieceRId ?

Comment: we use a JSonString representation of PieceRId new HttpDelete(getUrl(type)+"/"+JsonStringPieceId) ?

Comment: I have a question i know i can do a post request but with a delete how we use a compsite key to delete the record ? because json string doesn't work.

Comment: it's ok i used an url like this : http://....../id1/id2